# Pivot both numeric and strung non-numeric columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, sql-server-2014

I have a specific requirement to pivot up two columns, one numeric and one string. I am well versed with SQL pivot, however, could not reach a solution for this.

My raw data is like:

```
Country | Segment | Year | Parameter_Name | Parameter_Value_Numeric | Parameter_Value_String    
USA      | 1      | 2003 | Datapoint1     | 100                     | null
USA      | 1      | 2003 | Datapoint2     | 148                     | null
USA      | 1      | 2003 | Datapoint3     | null                    | Upper values(s)
USA      | 2      | 2003 | Datapoint1     | 121                     | null
USA      | 2      | 2003 | Datapoint2     | 180                     | null
USA      | 2      | 2003 | Datapoint3     | null                    | Medium values(s)
```

The results I want is something like:

```
Country  | Segment       | Year | Datapoint1     | Datapoint2     | Datapoint3
USA      | 1             | 2003 | 100            | 148            | Upper values(s)
USA      | 2             | 2003 | 121            | 180            | Medium values(s)
```

The issue being faced is that Datapoint1 & Datapoint2 are `float` and Datapoint3 is `nvarchar`. Hence, pivot is able to use only one of these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this below logic-

[DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9a5d5f27b3e8c5948cc5fd24105020e0)

```
SELECT Country,Segment,Year,
MAX(CASE WHEN Parameter_Name = 'Datapoint1' THEN Parameter_Value_Numeric END) Datapoint1,
MAX(CASE WHEN Parameter_Name = 'Datapoint2' THEN Parameter_Value_Numeric END) Datapoint2,
MAX(CASE WHEN Parameter_Name = 'Datapoint3' THEN Parameter_Value_String END) Datapoint3
FROM your_table
GROUP BY Country,Segment,Year
```

Comment: There is no need to use `ELSE` here. You could remove it